# How to remap tab key to Shift Left key?

Tags: keyboard

Unfortunately I found out that my tab key on keyboard does not work. Is there anyway I can map its functionalities (its autocomplete command function) to the left shift of the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind.

If you are trying to remap the keys in an X session (graphical user interface), you can use [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html) from the  x11-xserver-utils package to remap your keys via your `.xinitrc` file. (You can learn about the `.xinitrc` file by reading the [xinit man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/xinit.1.html). In the `.xinitrc` you would write:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 23 = Shift_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = Tab"
```

This would exchange the left shift with the tab key. (I have not tested this.)

The other solution applies if you are using a shell like Bash that uses [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). The Bash shell sources `~/.inputrc` and you can change the `complete` variable. Information about this is in the Bash manual on [readline init file syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html). However, mapping it to the left shift key (to the best of my knowledge) is not an option. Instead, you can map the file completion to a different escape sequence than tab. (To see what your keys are currently bound to, use the command `bind -p`, specifically `bind -p | grep complete` will show you whats bound to the `complete` variable; most likely it is bound to double esc and control-i.) You can map a different keyboard combination for `complete`.